# How did Scott activate the shrinking mechanism when he was in jail?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

In the scene where he is locked up in jail we see the ants carrying the miniaturized Ant Man suit to Scott with a scene cut showing him circumventing the jail bars in his shrunken form.

In the first instance Scott shrinks he had to physically apply the normal sized suit onto himself and activate the shrinking mechanism.

How is he able to shrink if, in his normal size, he can't interact with the miniaturized suit?

Comment: I think the ants pushed the button to expand the suit after they brought it in. I could be wrong about that though.

Comment: @Alario Yes, the suit was definitely full size when Scott put it on. The ants brought in a shrunken suit and then made it full sized. You may recall the ants rearranging into numbers next to the enlarged suit to do a count down telling Scott how many seconds he had to put on the suit.

Comment: Rofl. I thought it was a close up shot of the suit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ants, acting under the direct control of Dr. Pym dragged the suit into the cell. You see them next to the suit, which then enlarges (note our hero's look of surprise).

Although the actual button-press happens offscreen, if you listen to the *sound-effect* you can hear one of the ants pressing the hand button.

Comment: That, and when the ants begin their countdown (0:24-0:26 in the clip), you can clearly see the enlarged suit next to them before Scott picks it up.